# setOnItemLongClickListener within Dialog

Tags: android, listview, dialog, clicklistener

I keep getting a null pointer exception in the line where i try to create a new OnItemLongClickListener. Basically, what I want is to create a dialog box out of a ListView that displays options and I want them to be selectable. Here is my code:

```
private void viewPatientOptions(){
    LayoutInflater factory4 = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    final View textEntryView4 = factory4.inflate(R.layout.patient_dialog, null);
    patientOptionV = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.patientOptions);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,
            new ArrayList<String>
            (Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.patientOptions))));
    patientOptionV.setAdapter(adapter);
    patientOptionV.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            String itemValue = (String) patientOptionV
                    .getItemAtPosition(position);
            if(itemValue.equals("New Test")){
                Log.i(TAG, "Viewing Tools for new test");
                viewTools();
            }
            if(itemValue.equals("Gallery")){
                Log.i(TAG, "Viewing Gall");
                viewGall();
            }
            else
                //Do nothing
            return true;
        }
    });
    mViewPatientOptionsDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Patient ID: "+ PATIENT_ID_NUM)
            .setIcon(0)
            .setView(textEntryView4)
            .setNegativeButton(
                    R.string.dialog_cancel,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Caption dialog: CANCEL...");
                            openView(patientList);
                        }
                    })
            .create();
    mViewPatientOptionsDialog.show();
}
```

UPDATE: CANNOT POST ANSWER TO MY OWN QUESTION BUT I SOLVED THE PROBLEM. THANKS
Here is my answer:

Got it to work. Figured out that an AlertDialog.Builder has it's own set items method. Don't know what was actually wrong with my first approach but this code is working now:

```
private void viewPatientOptions(){
    LayoutInflater factory4 = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    final View textEntryView4 = factory4.inflate(R.layout.patient_dialog, null);
    mViewPatientOptionsDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Patient ID: "+PATIENT_ID)
            .setIcon(0)
            .setView(textEntryView4)
            .setItems(R.array.patientOptions, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog2, int item) {
                    if(item==2){
                        Log.i(TAG, "Viewing Tools");
                        viewTools();
                    }
                    if(item==0){
                        Log.i(TAG, "Viewing Gall");
                        //viewTools();
                    }
                    else
                        Log.e(TAG,"NOTHONG SELECTED");//do nothing
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(
                    R.string.dialog_cancel,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Caption dialog: CANCEL...");
                            openView(2);
                        }
                    })
            .create();
    mViewPatientOptionsDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Run the app with the debugger and find out what is null.

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: my ListView patientOptionV was coming up null for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You may be trying to access the ListView outside of the scope.

Replace `String itemValue = (String) patientOptionV.getItemAtPosition(position);` with the code in the snippet below `String itemValue = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);`.

```
@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    String itemValue = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

    ...
}
```